# Grep a range of filenames for lines containing a range of data

Tags: bash, grep, debian

Lets say I have logfiles in a directory, with date filenames, such as `20140122`, `20140123`, `20140124` and so on.

Inside these log files, every time I post to the log file I have a datetime string followed by the data, such as:

```
Thu Jan 23 02:04:48 EST 2014
bbb:Encryption of file: bbb has finished.
```

What I would like to do is grep for lines starting with a phrase, `bbb:`, with the datetime before it within a time range, such as `01:00:00 - 03:00:00` and found in files matching a date range such as `20140122-20140124`.

In this example, `grep` would ideally return the above two lines, as well as any other lines matching the criteria of a time between 1 and 3 am and starting with bbb:

Any suggestions?

Edit: I have decided to change from a file system to a database system so while I would still like to find an answer, for other people who may need something similar someday, this question can be closed now as is if you want.

Comment: Let's forget about grep being the answer to your dreams and tell us what actual parameters you want to pass to this miracle script, and also how we can deduce that "bbb" is a file.

Comment: well the parameters would be 2 8 digit figures, being the limit of the files that I need to search through, and a string that is the search word, the search word being bbb. Its not the file itself, its a line in the file. My post was a bit misleading, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
for file in 2014012{2..4}
do
  echo
  echo "<<<<-" $file "->>>>"
  grep --no-group-separator -B1 -e '^bbb:' $file | \
    awk '$4>="01:00:00" && $4<="03:00:00"{print $0;getline;print $0}'
done
```

Comment: This would possibly not work for me as I would not know what any of the dates or times would be. This could probably be modified to cater for that though, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should split your question in several less complex parts. "How can I get files with names in range", "how can I grep contents of a file" and so on.

Sorry, i did not understood what do you whant to grep, but you can find your files like this.

```
mkdir a{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}; ls | sort -n | sed -n '/a3/,/a6/p'; rm -r a{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

It creates sample dirs, gets the list of a dir, sorts files names as numbers, gets strings between a3 and a6 and clears it all.

And, yes, your should make sure, that files with your date name exists and get closest file if it does not. It could be your one more separate question how to do it.